# loading pydub.AudioSegment into librosa using librosa.load

Tags: python, librosa, pydub

I have loaded and performed modifications to an audio clip using `AudioSegment.from_mp3`.  I need to perform analysis on the clip and so I am attempting to load the file using `librosa.load()`. I know I could save the audio and then load it but it seems very inefficient. Every answer to this problem I can find is very messy.

I can get the raw data of the audio clip by using `audio_clip.raw_data` however this is in bytes and `load` only accepts  `str | int | PathLike | SoundFile | AudioFile | BinaryIO`. I don't know much about BinaryIO but is it possible to convert bytes (or `BytesIO`) to `BinaryIO`?

Here is the relevant code:

```py
audio_clip = AudioSegment.from_mp3("example.mp3")
#  ... perform modification
y, sr = librosa.load(somehow convert audio clip to a loadable format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the PCM data from `audio_clip.raw_data` as WAV data to a `BytesIO` object as shown in `load_from_bytes` below.
(Highly inspired by `AudioSegment.export()`)

Another possibilty is to avoid `librosa.load` and use the bytes directly since the file was already loaded into memory with pydub as shown in `convert_to_librosa_format` below.
(Also discussed in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810035/converting-audio-files-between-pydub-and-librosa))

```py
import io
import wave

import librosa
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment


def load_from_bytes(audio_clip: AudioSegment):
    with io.BytesIO() as data:
        with wave.open(data, "wb") as wavfile:
            wavfile.setnchannels(audio_clip.channels)
            wavfile.setsampwidth(audio_clip.sample_width)
            wavfile.setframerate(audio_clip.frame_rate)
            wavfile.writeframes(audio_clip.raw_data)
        data.seek(0)
        y, sr = librosa.load(data, sr=None, mono=False)
    return y, sr


def convert_to_librosa_format(audio_clip: AudioSegment):
    dtypes = {1: np.int8, 2: np.int16, 4: np.int32}
    bytes_per_sample = audio_clip.sample_width
    audio_dtype = dtypes[bytes_per_sample]
    audio_max = np.iinfo(audio_dtype).max
    y = np.frombuffer(audio_clip.raw_data, dtype=dtypes[bytes_per_sample])
    y = y / audio_max
    y = y.reshape((-1, audio_clip.channels)).T

    return y, audio_clip.frame_rate


# Test that the audio data is almost the same as librosa
test_file = "example.mp3"
y_load, sr_load = load_from_bytes(AudioSegment.from_file(test_file))
y_pd, sr_pd = convert_to_librosa_format(AudioSegment.from_file(test_file))
y_lr, sr_lr = librosa.load(test_file, sr=None, mono=False)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(y_lr, y_load, decimal=3)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(y_lr, y_pd, decimal=3)
```